# Lumen isn't reading the app key if too many requests occur

Tags: php, lumen

I am running lumen on my backend, and on the frontend I am using AJAX to make requests to the server every `5 seconds`. At first the requests run fine, but after about 20 requests I get the following error:

> The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.

In my `.env` file I have this:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=1jleJ3gqex79HZ39mP5nWgtX2u1HD8X1
```

What is causing this to happen and is there anyway to fix it?

One thing I read is that the file is getting locked and it isn't able to read the `.env` so it throws an error.

Comment: This is a [long standing issue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/env-not-reading-variables-sometimes). Reportedly solved by caching the config (`php artisan config:cache`).

Comment: lumen doesn't have `config:cache` Is there a way to add it?

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/orumad/lumen-config-cache